# Is this the right way of using ThenFetch() to load multiple collections?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, linq-to-nhibernate, fetching-strategy

I'm trying to load all the collections eagerly, using [NHibernate 3 alpha 1](http://nhforge.org/media/p/690.aspx). I'm wondering if this the right way of using ThenFetch()?

Properties with plural names are collections. The others are just a single object.

```
            IQueryable<T> milestoneInstances = Db.Find<T, IQueryable<T>>(db =>
            from mi in db
            where mi.RunDate == runDate
            select mi).Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone)
                .ThenFetch(m => m.PrimaryOwners)
                .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone)
                .ThenFetch(m => m.SecondaryOwners)
                .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone)
                .ThenFetch(m => m.Predecessors)
                .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone)
                .ThenFetch(m => m.Function)
                .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone)
                .ThenFetchMany(m => m.Jobs)
                .ThenFetch(j => j.Source)
                ;
```

I thought of asking this in the [NHibernate forums](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers) but unfortunately access to google groups is forbidden from where I am. I know [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360080/fabio-maulo) is here, so maybe the guys from the NHibernate team can shed some light on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, there's no "right" way to use `ThenFetch` in such a case. Your example works fine but SQL produced contains many joins to `Milestone`, which isn't that right.

Using `IQueryOver` instead of `IQueryable` allows you to use [complex syntax](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2972?focusedCommentId=22151#comment-22151) in `Fetch`:

```
Fetch(p => p.B) 
Fetch(p => p.B.C) // if B is not a collection ... or 
Fetch(p => p.B[0].C) // if B is a collection ... or 
Fetch(p => p.B.First().C) // if B is an IEnumerable (using .First() extension method)
```

So in your case it would be:

```
query // = session.QueryOver<X>()
    .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone).Eager
    .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone.PrimaryOwners).Eager
    .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone.SecondaryOwners).Eager
    .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone.Predecessors).Eager
    .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone.Function).Eager
    .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone.Jobs).Eager
    .Fetch(mi => mi.Milestone.Jobs.First().Source).Eager
```

Answer (score 3):

The one thing you are missing is that you should use FetchMany() and ThenFetchMany() is the child property is a collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
        IQueryable<T> milestoneInstances = Db.Find<T, IQueryable<T>>(db =>
        from mi in db
        where mi.RunDate == runDate
        select mi);

var fetch = milestoneInstances.Fetch(f => f.Milestone);
fetch.ThenFetch(f => f.PrimaryOwners);
fetch.ThenFetch(f => f.SecondaryOwners);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

As leora said, make sure when fetching children collections that you use

```
FetchMany()

ThenFetchMany()
```

A new Fetch, should pick up from the root, but this does not always happen. Sometimes you need to create them as separate queries or use Criteria Futures to batch up a multiple fetch.