# Eagerly fetch multiple collection properties (using QueryOver/Linq)?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I found 2 similar questions:

- [Multiple Fetches in linq to nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208723/multiple-fetches-in-linq-to-nhibernate)
- [Is this the right way of using ThenFetch() to load multiple collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397980/is-this-the-right-way-of-using-thenfetch-to-load-multiple-collections)

According to [this page](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html):

> Be careful not to eagerly fetch
>   multiple collection properties at the
>   same time. Although this statement
>   will work fine:
>
> ```
> var employees = session.Query<Employee>()
>     .Fetch(e => e.Subordinates)
>     .Fetch(e => e.Orders).ToList();
> ```
>
> It executes a Cartesian product query
>   against the database, so the total
>   number of rows returned will be the
>   total Subordinates times the total
>   orders.

Lets say I have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

What is the simplest way to eagerly load all persons with their Books, Articles, and Addresses using QueryOver/Linq (without returning a Cartesian product)?

Thanks

---

**Update:**

See [cremor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631802/cremor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814390/eagerly-fetch-multiple-collection-properties-using-queryover-linq/5814545#5814545) below and [Florian Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634872/florian-lim)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682668/how-to-resolve-poor-nhibernate-collection-initialization/5683564#5683564) in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682668/how-to-resolve-poor-nhibernate-collection-initialization). The following code works nicely, only one round-trip to the database.

```
var persons = session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Future<Person>();
var persons2 = session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Books).Eager
    .Future<Person>();
var persons3 = session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Articles).Eager
    .Future<Person>();
var persons4 = session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Addresses).Eager
    .Future<Person>();
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to use the linq provider if at all possible especially if you are using newer versions of nhibernate (>= 4.0).  As long as you have your collections mapped as ISets (requires .net framework >= 4) which we converted to such that we could do eager loading and avoid cartesian products.  I feel like this isn't something that is heavily advertised but I prefer this method where applicable over anything else :

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual ISet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public Person()
{
    this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
    this.Articles = new HashSet<Article>();
    this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
}
```

If you have your collections defined like the above then you can do the following and still avoid cartesian product issues:

```
var persons = session.Query<Person>()
                     .FetchMany(x => x.Books)
                     .FetchMany(x => x.Articles)
                     .FetchMany(x => x.Addresses)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IList<Person> GetAll()
{
    var persons = session.QueryOver<Person>()
        .Future<Person>();

    session.QueryOver<Person>()
        .Fetch(x => x.Books).Eager
        .Future<Person>();

    session.QueryOver<Person>()
        .Fetch(x => x.Articles).Eager
        .Future<Person>();

    session.QueryOver<Person>()
        .Fetch(x => x.Addresses).Eager
        .Future<Person>();

    return persons.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Please add a description explaining what you did